# How to create table with rowspan

Tags: php, html, arrays

I retrieved data from a sql query that I parsed into an array.

```
[D20180821] => Array
    (
        [mark01] => Array
            (
                [PARIS] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [event_id] => 1
                                [evnet] => OPEN_TICKET_D
                                [id] => 80
                                [time] => 2018-08-22 06:56:41
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [event_id] => 5
                                [evnet] => CLOSE_TICKET_D
                                [id] => 651
                                [time] => 2018-08-22 11:31:00
                            )

                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [event_id] => 4
                                [evnet] => GO
                                [id] => 82
                                [time] => 2018-08-22 11:50:35
                            )

                    )

                [LONDON] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [event_id] => 1
                                [evnet] => OPEN_TICKET_D
                                [id] => 79
                                [time] => 2018-08-22 06:56:38
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [event_id] => 5
                                [evnet] => CLOSE_TICKET_D
                                [id] => 652
                                [time] => 2018-08-22 11:29:00
                            )

                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [event_id] => 4
                                [evnet] => GO
                                [id] => 81
                                [time] => 2018-08-22 11:50:35
                            )

                        [3] => Array
                            (
                                [event_id] => 6
                                [evnet] => CLOSE_TICKET_R
                                [id] => 647
                                [time] => 2018-08-24 10:40:00
                            )

                    )

            )

        [rows] => 2
    )
```

I would like to create a table knowing that there are rowspan to do. To prepare this table I calculated the rowspan in `[rows]`.

Here is an example of the painting I want to build

[image]

I can not get away with the lopps to build this table

thank you very much

Comment: read about nested foreach loop

Comment: first check which  one is bigger, so loop runs that many times, then check if the city sub arrays less then count than just keep empty

Comment: have you tried something, i would segust you try yourself , and if cant solve it, then show what you have done, we will help  you fixing it

Comment: Please show your attempt to solve the problem otherwise the question is far too broad and therefore off topic for SO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Input Data

```
$tab=Array(
        'D20180821' => Array
            (
                'mark01' => Array
                    (
                        'PARIS' => Array
                            (
                                '0' => Array
                                    (
                                        'event_id' => '1',
                                        'evnet' => 'OPEN_TICKET_DEPLOY',
                                        'id' => '80',
                                        'time' => '2018-08-22 06:56:41'
                                    ),
                                '1' => Array
                                    (
                                        'event_id' => '5',
                                        'evnet' => 'CLOSE_TICKET_DEPLOY',
                                        'id' => '651',
                                        'time' => '2018-08-22 11:31:00'
                                    ),
                                '2' => Array
                                    (
                                        'event_id' => '4',
                                        'evnet' => 'POST_GO',
                                        'id' => '82',
                                        'time' => '2018-08-22 11:50:35'
                                    )
                            ),
                        'LONDON' => Array
                            (
                                '0' => Array
                                    (
                                        'event_id' => '1',
                                        'evnet' => 'OPEN_TICKET_DEPLOY',
                                        'id' => '79',
                                        'time' => '2018-08-22 06:56:38'
                                    ),
                                '1'=> Array
                                    (
                                        'event_id' => '5',
                                        'evnet' => 'CLOSE_TICKET_DEPLOY',
                                        'id' => '652',
                                        'time' => '2018-08-22 11:29:00'
                                    ),
                                '2' => Array
                                    (
                                        'event_id' => '4',
                                        'evnet' => 'POST_GO',
                                        'id' => '81',
                                        'time' => '2018-08-22 11:50:35'
                                    ),
                                '3' => Array
                                    (
                                        'event_id' => '6',
                                        'evnet' => 'CLOSE_TICKET_REMOVE',
                                        'id' => '647',
                                        'time' => '2018-08-24 10:40:00'
                                    )
                            )
                    ),

                'rows' => '2'
            )
    );
```

The Code: (you can test it @ phptester.net)

```
echo '<table border class="table table-striped">';
    echo '<tr>';
        echo '<th>Event</th>
              <th>mark</th>
              <th>Place</th>
              <th>OPEN_TICKET_D</th>
              <th>CLOSE_TICKET_D</th>
              <th>GO</th>
              <th>CLOSE_TICKET_R</th>';
    echo '</tr>';
    foreach ($tab as $k => $qal) {
        $rowspan = $qal['rows'];
        unset($qal['rows']);
        $first = true;
        foreach ($qal as $mark => $cities) {
            foreach ($cities as $city => $details) {
                echo '<tr>';
                    if ($first) {
                        echo "<td rowspan='$rowspan'>$k</td>";
                        $first = false;
                    }
                    echo "<td>$mark</td>";
                    echo "<td>$city</td>";
                    $temp = array_replace(
                                [
                                    'OPEN_TICKET_DEPLOY' => '',
                                    'CLOSE_TICKET_DEPLOY' => '',
                                    'POST_GO' => '',
                                    'CLOSE_TICKET_REMOVE' => ''
                                ],
                                array_column($details, 'time', 'evnet')
                            );
                    foreach ($temp as $val) {
                        echo "<td>$val</td>";
                    }
                echo '</tr>';
            }
        }
    }
echo '</table>';
```

Output:

[image]

After storing the `rows` value, I remove it from the array so that it is not iterated in the next foreach loop.

The cell that contains the rowspan attribute must be echoed only once, that is why I am using a `$first` variable and checking for `true`|`false`.

As for the deepest subarray data, I am `array_column()` and `array_replace()` to ensure that all expected columns are represented, have a default value, and are in the correct order before they are looped.  This part could have also been performed with a series of `isset()` conditions before echoing hardcoded keys -- I arbitrarily chose to use array functions instead.

---

Here is the alternate syntax:

```
echo '<table border class="table table-striped">';
    echo '<tr>';
        echo '<th>Event</th>
              <th>mark</th>
              <th>Place</th>
              <th>OPEN_TICKET_D</th>
              <th>CLOSE_TICKET_D</th>
              <th>GO</th>
              <th>CLOSE_TICKET_R</th>';
    echo '</tr>';
    foreach ($tab as $k => $qal) {
        $rowspan = $qal['rows'];
        unset($qal['rows']);
        $first = true;
        foreach ($qal as $mark => $cities) {
            foreach ($cities as $city => $details) {
                echo '<tr>';
                    if ($first) {
                        echo "<td rowspan='$rowspan'>$k</td>";
                        $first = false;
                    }
                    echo "<td>$mark</td>";
                    echo "<td>$city</td>";
                    echo '<td>' , (isset($details[0]['time']) ? $details[0]['time'] : '') , '</td>'; 
                    echo '<td>' , (isset($details[1]['time']) ? $details[1]['time'] : '') , '</td>'; 
                    echo '<td>' , (isset($details[2]['time']) ? $details[2]['time'] : '') , '</td>'; 
                    echo '<td>' , (isset($details[3]['time']) ? $details[3]['time'] : '') , '</td>'; 
                echo '</tr>';
            }
        }
    }
echo '</table>';
```